T3 Stack: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createCaller' before initialization
I want to use tRPC with mutations to upload a file in Next Js / T3 Stack with Supabase.
But no POST requests are working. The default 'post' mutation from the T3 stack template also does not work.
POST /api/trpc/files.uploadFile?batch=1 500 in 879ms
 ⨯ ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createCaller' before initialization
    at Module.createCaller (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server/api/root.ts:4:59)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/trpc/server.ts:33:65)
    at (rsc)/./src/trpc/server.ts (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\app\api\trpc\[trpc]\route.js:395:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server/auth.ts:14:70)
    at (rsc)/./src/server/auth.ts (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\app\api\trpc\[trpc]\route.js:351:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server/api/trpc.ts:12:70)
    at (rsc)/./src/server/api/trpc.ts (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\app\api\trpc\[trpc]\route.js:340:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\01 Projects\lib\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43) {
  type: 'ReferenceError',
  page: '/api/trpc/files.uploadFile'
}

TRPCClientError: Invalid response or stream interrupted
​​
cause: Error: Invalid response or stream interrupted
​​
columnNumber: 9
​​
data: undefined
​​
fileName: "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js line 531 > eval"
​​
lineNumber: 54
​​
message: "Invalid response or stream interrupted"
​​
meta: undefined
​​
name: "TRPCClientError"
​​
shape: undefined
​​
stack: "TRPCClientError@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/TRPCClientError.mjs:54:9\nfrom@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/TRPCClientError.mjs:45:16\nunstable_httpBatchStreamLink/</</</<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/links/httpBatchStreamLink.mjs:142:102\npromise callback*unstable_httpBatchStreamLink/</</<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/links/httpBatchStreamLink.mjs:141:20\nsubscribe@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:33:27\ntap/</<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/operators.mjs:84:27\nsubscribe@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:33:27\nloggerLink/</</<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/links/loggerLink.mjs:171:21\nsubscribe@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:33:27\ncreateChain/<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/links/internals/createChain.mjs:25:21\nsubscribe@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:33:27\nstartIfNeeded@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/operators.mjs:38:35\nshare/</<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/operators.mjs:67:13\nsubscribe@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:33:27\nobservableToPromise/promise<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:87:33\nobservableToPromise@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/observable/observable.mjs:75:21\nrequestAsPromise@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/internals/TRPCUntypedClient.mjs:27:112\nmutation@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/client/dist/internals/TRPCUntypedClient.mjs:44:21\nmutationFn@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@trpc/react-query/dist/shared/hooks/createHooksInternal.mjs:195:31\nfn@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/modern/mutation.js:72:29\nrun@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/modern/retryer.js:91:49\nstart@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/modern/retryer.js:132:9\nexecute@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/modern/mutation.js:107:40\nasync*mutate@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/modern/mutationObserver.js:69:34\nuseMutation/mutate<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/modern/useMutation.js:30:18\nhandleFileChange/reader.onloadend@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/FileUpload.tsx:27:49\nEventHandlerNonNull*handleFileChange@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/FileUpload.tsx:22:13\ncallCallback@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20565:14\ninvokeGuardedCallbackImpl@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20614:16\ninvokeGuardedCallback@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20689:29\ninvokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20703:25\nexecuteDispatch@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32128:42\nprocessDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32160:22\nprocessDispatchQueue@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32173:37\ndispatchEventsForPlugins@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32184:23\ndispatchEventForPluginEventSystem/<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32374:12\nbatchedUpdates$1@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24953:12\nbatchedUpdates@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28844:12\ndispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32373:17\ndispatchEvent@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30141:38\ndispatchDiscreteEvent@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30112:18\nEventListener.handleEvent*addEventBubbleListener@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30361:10\naddTrappedEventListener@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32277:29\nlistenToNativeEvent@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32216:26\nlistenToAllSupportedEvents/<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32227:30\nlistenToAllSupportedEvents@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32222:21\nhydrateRoot$1@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:37940:29\nhydrateRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:38526:10\nexports.hydrateRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/client.js:17:16\nhydrate/<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:197:60\nstartTransition@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.development.js:2597:25\nhydrate@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:197:24\n@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-next-dev.js:10:5\nappBootstrap/<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-bootstrap.js:57:9\nloadScriptsInSequence@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-bootstrap.js:23:16\nappBootstrap@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-bootstrap.js:56:26\n@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-next-dev.js:8:32\n(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-next-dev.js@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1731260781255:266:1\noptions.factory@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1731260781255:715:31\n__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1731260781255:37:33\n__webpack_exec__@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1731260781255:1996:61\n@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1731260781255:1997:154\nwebpackJsonpCallback@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1731260781255:1387:46\n@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1731260781255:9:61\n"

tRPC SHOULD config be correct, and should be able to run mutations, as I followed the installation guide. Because the default "post" also does not work, Supabase and the submission of FormData shouldn't be the problem.
What leads into the errors is the createCaller():
// src/trpc/server.ts

...
const caller = createCaller(createContext);

export const { trpc: api, HydrateClient } = createHydrationHelpers<AppRouter>(
    caller,
    getQueryClient,
);

// src/server/api/root.ts

...
export const createCaller = createCallerFactory(appRouter);


In my case this error occurred when I called tRPC procedure in NextAuth's config:
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ user }) {
    const expiredSessions = await api.user.removeExpiredSessions({ id: user.id });
  }
}

And I replaced it with direct access to the database:
callbacks: {
  async signIn({ user }) {
    const expiredSessions = await db
      .delete(sessions)
      .where(and(eq(sessions.userId, user.id), lt(sessions.expires, new Date())))
      .returning();
  }
}

Maybe it will be helpful for you.
P.S. I've resolved this issue just with the method of elimination :)

Nice to meet you. I have read your issue.
Ensure that your tRPC router is configured properly to handle mutations. Confirm that the endpoint is correctly defined and accessible and make sure your Supabase project is set up correctly, including tables, permissions, and storage buckets.
Ensure the method you're using to handle file uploads on the frontend is compatible with how tRPC expects the data and use  FormData for file uploads, as it is necessary when sending files in requests.
Ensure all necessary environment variables are correctly set up and accessible in your application, particularly those that are needed for connecting to Supabase.
By following these steps and considerations, you should be able to identify and resolve the issues with your file uploads using tRPC in your Next.js application.
If you want, I can support you.

tRPC SHOULD config be correct, and should be able to run mutations, as I followed the installation guide. Because the default "post" also does not work, Supabase and the submission of FormData shouldn't be the problem.
What leads into the errors is the createCaller():
// src/trpc/server.ts

...
const caller = createCaller(createContext);

export const { trpc: api, HydrateClient } = createHydrationHelpers<AppRouter>(
    caller,
    getQueryClient,
);

// src/server/api/root.ts
export const createCaller = createCallerFactory(appRouter);

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
